# Rails how to send params[:commit] value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a blog application in which I am trying to send some values like

1. post.id
2. params[:commit] (value )

So from my show action I am sending these 2 values to my edit action in my posts controller but i am unable to collect params[:commit] value ..in my case for approve it will send 'approve' and for decline it will send 'decline' but it is not sending 

[posts/show.html.erb]

```
<div id="post_content">
    <h1 class="title"><%= @post.title %></h1>
    <p class="date">
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
         <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
          <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

          <%= link_to "approve",[:edit,@post] ,commit: "Approve"%>
        <%= link_to "decline",[:edit,@post],commit: "decline" %>

        <% end %>
    </p>
    <p class="body"><%= @post.body %></p>

    <div id="comments">
        <h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h2>
        <%= render @post.comments %>

        <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
        <%= render "comments/form" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

[posts_controller.rb]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
        @posts = Post.user_post(current_user).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end 

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show    
        @post=find_params
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)           
        @post.user = current_user
        if @post.save
            Post.upload(params[:post][:files],@post.id)         
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = find_params
        puts "cccccccccc#{params[:commit]}"
        Post.up(@post.id,params[:commit])
    end

    def update
        @post = find_params

        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = find_params
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        end

        def find_params
            Post.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your link_to tag according to this.

```
    <%= link_to "approve", edit_post_path(@post, commit: "Approve") %>
    <%= link_to "decline", edit_post_path(@post, commit: "Decline" %>
```

Comment: And do i collect commit value in my edit action of my posts controller

Comment: Using params[:commit]

Comment: def edit
  @post = find_params
  puts "cccccccccc#{params[:commit]}"
  
 end

Comment: I have these links in my show page and when i click any of these link i want to send id as well as the params[:commit] to my edit controller

Comment: @aniket Check whether your links contain the 'commit' attribute in your anchor tags.

Comment: yes i have updated my code with the answer you provided